# DataRow value missing after InsertAt() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I have one sample code shown below.

```
DataRow dr = DTSource.Rows[rowIndex]; //getting specified index row
DTSource.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex); // deleting specified row
DTSource.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowIndex - 1); // adding the row placed just above of the deleted row
```

Here, after inserting the particular row to the specified index, the data table showing an empty row at the recently inserted place. How can i add the row with the data instead of this empty row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Mnieto and Tim Schmelter Answers, I have changed my code like this.

```
 DataRow dr = DTSource.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < DTSource.Columns.Count; i++)                    
                    dr[i] = DTSource.Rows[rowIndex][i];
```

Now it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

dr is deleted. That is because data table shows an empty row. Let see step by step:

```
DataRow dr = DTSource.Rows[rowIndex];
```

You save a row in dr variable

```
DTSource.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
```

You delete that row. dr variable is now pointing to a deleted row.

```
DTSource.Rows.InsertAt(dr, rowIndex - 1);
```

You are inserting a deleted row in another position

If you want to move a row position you should to do a deep copy of the datarow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Removes the row at the specified index from the collection.
>   When a row is removed, all data in that row is lost. ...

So you need to persist the data temporarily, for example by using `row.ItemArray`

```
DataRow row = DTSource.Rows[rowIndex];         //getting specified index row
var data = row.ItemArray;                      // all fields of that row
DTSource.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);              // removes row and it's data 
row.ItemArray = data;                          // reassign data
DTSource.Rows.InsertAt(row, rowIndex - 1);     // adding the row placed just above of
```